# Openlayers 3 can't load WMS Layer Tiles

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, wms

Maybe this could be a duplicated, but I can't find the right answer.

I'm using `EPSG:25830` to default projection of my map. For this I've used `proj4js` :

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:25830", "+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

var bounds25830 = [712397.500, 4374797.500, 742202.500, 4394802.500];
var proj25830 = ol.proj.get('EPSG:25830');
proj25830.setExtent(bounds25830);
```

Now I'm declaring some WMS Layers and adding to my map :

```
var ignBase = new ol.layer.Tile({
    name: 'IGN Base',
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
        params: {'FORMAT': 'image/png', 
                'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                transparent : false,
                tiled : true, 
                LAYERS: 'IGNBaseTodo',
                STYLES: '',
        }
    })
});

var layerVectorVacia = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title:'Vacía',
    name: 'base'
});

var groupCapasBase = new ol.layer.Group({
    name: 'Capas Base',
    layers: [layerVectorVacia, ignBase]
});

var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat : ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2)
});
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers  : [
        groupCapasBase
    ],
    target  : 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({ attribution : false }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
    view    : new ol.View({
        projection: proj25830,
        zoom      : 5,
        center    : [727300.000, 4384800.000]
    })
});
```

In the map, nothing is rendered, and if I look at the network panel, it appears that images have not been loaded. My first thought was that the request is badly formatted, but if I copy and paste some of the failing request in a browser, it returns the right image.

**EDIT**

> I've noticed that if I use "FORMAT" : "image/jpeg" intead of
>   "image/png" is rendering properly.

Comment: `if I copy and paste some of the failing request in a browser, it returns the right image`, can you clarify what you mean by this (**some**), what if you paste all of the request into a browser?  Is it just image/png that fails, what about other supported image formats such as `image/png8`.  As an aside too, I see you are requesting version 1.1.0, but the service doesn't appear to support that version (a 1.1.0 GetCapabilities request gives a 1.1.1 response)

Comment: Sorry, just a typo the version, I'm using `1.1.1`, What I meant by some, is in fact all the tiles of this services using `image/png`, if I use `png8` as you said, it works. I'll edit with some images. If you want to write an answer I'll mark as accepted. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `image/png` doesn't work whilst `image/jpeg` does, possibly some driver issue on the server.  A [GetCapabilities request](http://www.ign.es/wms-inspire/ign-base?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1&) to the service shows that there are a number of image formats as below:

```
<GetMap>
  <Format>image/png</Format>
  <Format>application/pdf</Format>
  <Format>image/geotiff</Format>
  <Format>image/geotiff8</Format>
  <Format>image/gif</Format>
  <Format>image/gif;subtype=animated</Format>
  <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
  <Format>image/png8</Format>
  <Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
  <Format>image/svg</Format>
  <Format>image/svg xml</Format>
  <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
  <Format>image/tiff</Format>
  <Format>image/tiff8</Format>
```

If you want to use a portable network graphic image format, you could try the alternatively listed variants `image/png8` or `image/png; mode=8bit`.

It would be worth contacting the service provider (contact details are in the GetCapabilities response), to make them aware of the situation.